In quartal voicings, what makes a voicing minor, vague and dissonant?

As I was reading through a book, there was this line that went
"some vertical voicings are clearly minor, some are vague, and others pungently dissonant."
I was wondering, which notes make quartal voicings minor, or dissonant?
And also, the chord given is "I-".
But there are many different notes like Bb or Ab that give enough reason to make it I-6 or I-7 or any other chords. How come is it simply I-?

May I ask what book this is?



...I was wondering, which notes make quartal voicings minor, or dissonant?

Those descriptions, along with "vague", do not really depend on quartal voicings or quartal harmony. In terms of tonality, minor is quality of the modal scale degrees ^3 ^6. In terms of chord quality minor is a quality of the chord's third. In cases where these tones are omitted or occur in both major and minor forms, the quality can be called "vague." Dissonance is traditional defined as any interval which is not consonant. The consonances being perfect unisons, octaves, and fifths, along with major and minor thirds and sixths. (You can also think of consonances as those intervals of major and minor triads in root position or first inversion.)

G C F with a C root is vague, because the third is omitted.
F Bb Eb with a C root is "clearly" minor, because the Eb provides a third, and that third is minor.
Eb Ab Db with a C root is "pungently" dissonant, because the Db is a dissonant minor second above the root C.


And also, the chord given is "I-". But there are many different notes like Bb or Ab that give enough reason to make it I-6 or I-7 or any other chords. How come is it simply I-?

Sometimes harmonic analysis is done at a fairly deep, abstract level where you might label only chord roots with no labeling of chord qualities or inversions. That seems to be the author's point here. They labeled the passage simply I to indicate it is harmonically only a tonic chord. The difference is between strictly separating harmony as only chord root progressions from the melodic implications which come from labels like Cm7sus4, i6/3, etc.
In the example you could use chord labels like Csus4, Cm7sus4, and maybe something awful, like Absus4/C. But the musical point of the passage seems really specifically about a pedal C in the bass, stacked perfect fourths "quartal" voicings, and an undulating melodic motion by steps. You could more simply labels the whole thing Cm7sus4 and then call the other RH stuff upper and lower neighbor motion. But notice how all of that descriptive information is about what is happening melodically rather than harmonically. If you want to just encapsulate the harmony, it is simply all a tonic chord and the tonality from which the melodic detail is drawn is phrygian. So, that reduces harmonically to C phrygian: i. That is the author's point.

In quartal harmony there is no concept of major and minor. If you embed quartal harmony into Rameau harmony you will find chords with notes more defining of a minor scale and ones less defining, which leads to the categories you find here.
If we deduce a 7 note scale from harmony of fourths we get C - F - Bb - Eb - Ab - Db - Gb, so C - Db - Eb - F - Gb - Ab - Bb. So this leads to what is sometimes called a scale of Locrian mode, which is more related to the minor tonality. Here the author builds the scale on the first fourth as tonal center, so in this case F - Gb - Ab - Bb - C - Db - Eb, which gives a scale of Phrygian mode, which is related to minor tonality as well. Generally quartal harmony gives you the minor 7th, the minor 3rd, the minor 6th, and the minor 9th, all of which are more or less characteristic for minor tonality. Quintal harmony on the other hand gives you the mirrored scale, so a scale of Lydian mode. This gives you the perfect 5th, the major 2nd, the major 6th, the major 3rd, and the major 7th, all of which are more or less indicative of major tonality.
Harmony of fourths generally leads to a rather uniform level of dissonance. The only hard dissonance is the minor 2nd, and to some degree the diminished fifth. Voicings where these intervals interact with the root (so mostly if they are the lowest note above the root) will sound somewhat harsh.

The "I-" indication is saying that the passage overall expresses I-; it's not referring to a single chord.
In quartal voicings, the character of the chord depends on the specific notes in it. However, the posted example is referring to the relationships of the various chords to the C octave in the bass.

The first chord, G-C-F, will have a sound on the ambiguous side, since it doesn't have an Eb, which, combined with C, gives the characteristic sound of C minor.
The second chord, because it contains Eb (and to a lesser extent, Bb) is more clearly minor (the Bb being part of a C-7 chord).
The third chord is quite dissonant against the bass C because of its Db.

Quartal voicings are inherently dissonant within themselves, because they contain a seventh. However, in jazz and popular music — and especially in music dominated by quartal sounds – the sevenths are not heard as dissonant in the way they would in much classical music.
In the posted example, all of the voicings use only perfect fourths, which creates a "softer" dissonance: there are no tritones or major sevenths. But those more dissonant intervals can occur within such a voicing, such as F-B-E, which might show up in the context of C major, for example.
Quartal voicing are often used as shown above — to create the "feel" of a key or mode but without committing to chords (i.e., triads and seventh chords) that unambiguously define it.

Question - since C Phrygian is a mode of Ab, why would the writer have used standard Cm key signature, then have to flatten every D note with an accidental. Doesn't make sense to me!

@Tim That’s the convention for diatonic modes—use the signature of the parallel major or minor according to whether it’s a “major” mode (e.g., Lydian) or “minor” mode (e.g., Dorian).

'Key signature for writing in modes' makes interesting reading. Seems it could  (and does) go either way. We never have the problem with Aeolian so why the others?

@Tim Modes and keys don't quite fit together as ideas. There are two kinds of key -- major and minor -- that correspond to two of the major scale's modes -- Ionian and Aeolian. There are no keys matching the other modes. Now, C Phrygian must be written with SOME key signature or other, so what to do? Writing the key as Ab Major gives the wrong signals if C is supposed to be the tonic -- it wouldn't "look Phrygian". Using the C Minor key signature says "The key is C minor but we're flatting every 9" and that does indeed "look Phrygian". That's my 2c anyway...
